# iOS How to implement open host app in broadcast upload extension?

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I see other live app can open host app when use control center record.

```
[self.extensionContext openURL:YOUR_NSURL completionHandler:nil];
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myapp://"]]];
```

or

```
func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self
    while responder != nil {
        if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
            return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }
    return false
}
```

is doesn't work.any one know this?
Thank you for you time.best wishes

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231573/error-when-opening-main-app-from-autofill-credential-provider-extension