# Error when opening main app from Autofill Credential Provider extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, exc-bad-access

Problem: The aim of this post is to find what's wrong with the code below and find the appropriate solution to open the main app from its Autofill Credential Provider extension target.

Attempt 1: I have a URL scheme set as "open" as shown in the image below:

> [image: Thread 3: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)]

I then attempt to call this function from my extension viewcontroller:

```
    func openMainApp()
{
    let urlStr: String = "open"
    let url2 = NSURL(string: urlStr)
    self.extensionContext.open(url2! as URL)
}
```

This crashes before at the open function before opening the main app with the following message:

> Thread 2: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

I think everything is set up properly to open the app. What am I missing?

Attempt 2: Tried a new configuration to avoid "unwrapping" of url problem and invalid url problems below, changed url scheme to "open:", and set a breakpoint at the "print(url)" line to assure url was formed. Breakpoint vars documented below the code.

Still getting: Thread 3: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

```
    func openMainApp()
{
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "open:")
            if let url = urlComponents?.url {
                print(url)
                self.extensionContext.open(url)
            } else {
                print ("NIL URL")
            }
}
```

> urlComponents Foundation.URLComponents?   some
> url Foundation.URL  "open:"
> _url    NSURL   "open:" 0x0000000281695540
> baseNSObject@0  NSObject
> _urlString  id  0x100001d80 0x0000000100001d80
> _baseURL    id  0x800010000010001   0x0800010000010001
> _clients    NSString    "open:" 0x8521474e0e31dd15
> _reserved   NSURL   0x0000000000000000

Title of the Thread throwing the exception:

> ExtensionKit`__62-[EXExtensionContextImplementation openURL:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2:

Comment: `open` isn't a great url scheme to choose for your app.  Regardless, you need to use `open:` to make a valid url

Comment: I’ll give that a shot. Thanks. Given that all I need is for it to open, what is the issue with the url scheme? Does it need to be unique for another reason?

Comment: Still has the same issue when using "open:". Thread 2: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

Comment: These are the url properties when the open function is executed url2 Foundation.URL "open:" 
_url NSURL "open:"

Comment: I mistakingly put "today extension" in the title. In reality this is a credentialproviderview extension.

Comment: You are force unwrapping a URL that is probably `nil`. Don't force unwrap and also don't use `NSURL` in Swift, use `URL`. URL schemes do need to be unique and there is no "registry" where you can ensure uniqueness, so it is best to pick something that is likely to be unique, such as your app name or a variation.

Comment: Ok I modified to avoid force unwrapping and changed to :open. Still getting Thread 3: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

Comment: Edited to show title of the thread throwing exception: ExtensionKit`__62-[EXExtensionContextImplementation openURL:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2:

Comment: Have you typed "open:" into Safari?  Does it open your app?  Have you tried with a different url scheme?  Is this your actual code?  Do you have a completion handler on the `open` call as the exception says that it is occurring in a block

Comment: The other question I would have is whether a credential auto fill extension is even permitted to call `open(url)`

Comment: I have tried it about 100 different ways. With and without completion handlers. when I try to open my url from safari (currently "open://") I get a toast that says "Safari cannot open this page because the address is invalid"

Comment: When I register it as just "open:" it simply provides search results

Comment: Ok I changed the info.plist scheme back to just "open" and now I can open the app from safari using "open://". Still no luck from the app side. I see your answer below and if I don't find another solution, I will reward you the bounty for pointing out that it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Credential Provider extensions are not permitted to open urls.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsextensioncontext/1416791-open)

> Each extension point determines whether to support this method, or under which conditions to support this method. In iOS, the Today and iMessage app extension points support this method. An iMessage app extension can use this method only to open its parent app, and only if the parent app is shown on the iOS home screen.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to launch the main app from autofill extension using responder chain like:

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: "myapp://") else { return }

let selectorOpenURL = #selector(UIApplication.openURL)

var responder = rootViewController.next
while let nextResponder = responder {
    if nextResponder.responds(to: selectorOpenURL) {
        nextResponder.perform(selectorOpenURL, with: url)
        break
    }
    responder = nextResponder.next
}
```

where `rootViewController` is the view controller you present for this extension.